# Cannot get column to show up in alphabetic order

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<script runat="server">

Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strFilter As String
Dim objCmd 
Dim objReader As SqlDataReader
Dim DBComm As SqlCommand
Dim DBAdapt As SqlDataAdapter

Sub DBConnect
  SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("CString")
  SQLConn.Open()
End Sub

Sub DBDisconnect
  SQLConn.close()
End Sub

Sub Page_Load
  Dim ThisFilter As Object = ViewState("vsFilter")
    If Not (ThisFilter Is Nothing) Then
        strFilter = CStr(ThisFilter)
    Else
        strFilter = "All"
    End If
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindData(True)
    End If
End Sub

Sub BindData(ByVal GetFresh As Boolean)
    Call DBConnect()

    Dim DTable As DataTable = Nothing
    If ViewState("vsSortData") Is Nothing Or GetFresh Then
        If Session("Agency_Name") = "Main Company" Then
            strSQL = "SELECT LOGIN.Login_ID, LOGIN.Login_Last_Name + ', ' + LOGIN.Login_First_Name + ' ' + CASE WHEN Login_Middle_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Middle_Name) END AS FullName, AGENCY.Agency_Name, '(' + Substring(Login_Phone, 0, 4) + ') ' + Substring(Login_Phone, 4, 3) + '-' + Substring(Login_Phone, 7, 4) as Phone, LOGIN.Login_Email, CASE WHEN Login_Type = 'U' THEN 'User' WHEN Login_Type = 'I' THEN 'ISC' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Type) END AS LoginType, CASE WHEN Login_Account_Active = 'T' THEN 'Yes' WHEN Login_Account_Active = 'F' THEN 'No' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Account_Active) END AS AcctActive FROM LOGIN INNER JOIN AGENCY ON LOGIN.Login_Agency_ID = AGENCY.Agency_ID WHERE LOGIN.Login_Deleted = 'F'"
        Else
            strSQL = "SELECT LOGIN.Login_ID, LOGIN.Login_Last_Name + ', ' + LOGIN.Login_First_Name + ' ' + CASE WHEN Login_Middle_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Middle_Name) END AS FullName, AGENCY.Agency_Name, '(' + Substring(Login_Phone, 0, 4) + ') ' + Substring(Login_Phone, 4, 3) + '-' + Substring(Login_Phone, 7, 4) as Phone, LOGIN.Login_Email, CASE WHEN Login_Type = 'U' THEN 'User' WHEN Login_Type = 'I' THEN 'ISC' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Type) END AS LoginType, CASE WHEN Login_Account_Active = 'T' THEN 'Yes' WHEN Login_Account_Active = 'F' THEN 'No' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, Login_Account_Active) END AS AcctActive FROM LOGIN INNER JOIN AGENCY ON LOGIN.Login_Agency_ID = AGENCY.Agency_ID WHERE LOGIN.Login_Deleted = 'F' AND AGENCY.Agency_Name='" & Session("Agency_Name") & "'"
        End If
        DBComm = New SqlCommand(strSQL, SQLConn)
        DBAdapt = New SqlDataAdapter(DBComm)
        Dim DSet As New DataSet()
        Try
            DBAdapt.Fill(DSet)
            DTable = DSet.Tables(0)
        Catch EXC As SqlException
            Me.lblMsg2.Text = EXC.Message
            Return
        Finally
            SQLConn.Close()
        End Try
        ViewState("vsSortData") = DTable
    Else
        DTable = CType(ViewState("vsSortData"), DataTable)
    End If
    If strFilter = "All" Then
        DTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Empty
    Else
        DTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FullName LIKE '" & strFilter & "%'"
    End If
    Me.datagrid.DataSource = DTable.DefaultView
    Me.datagrid.DataBind()
    BuildAlphaPager()

    Call DBDisconnect()
End Sub

Sub BuildAlphaPager()
    Dim DTable As DataTable
    If ViewState(("strLetter")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim arrLetters As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "All"}
        DTable = New DataTable()
        DTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Letter", GetType(String)))
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To arrLetters.Length - 1
            Dim DRow As DataRow = DTable.NewRow()
            DRow(0) = arrLetters(i)
            DTable.Rows.Add(DRow)
        Next i
        ViewState("strLetter") = DTable
    Else
        DTable = CType(ViewState("strLetter"), DataTable)
    End If
    Me.rptLetters.DataSource = DTable.DefaultView
    Me.rptLetters.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub rptLetters_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header) Then
    ElseIf (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        Dim lnkAlpha As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lnkAlpha"), LinkButton)
        lnkAlpha.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Letter")
        lnkAlpha.CommandName = "Filter"
        lnkAlpha.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Letter")
        Dim DRView As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
        If CStr(DRView(0)) = strFilter Then
            lnkAlpha.Enabled = False
        End If
    ElseIf (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer) Then
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub rptLetters_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Filter" Then
        strFilter = CStr(e.CommandArgument)
        ViewState("vsFilter") = strFilter
        BindData(False)
    End If
End Sub

</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">

<font size="1" color="#FF0000"><strong><asp:label id="lblMsg2" runat="server" /></strong></font>

<div align="center"><h3>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLetters" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptLetters_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptLetters_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAlpha" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</h3></div>

<asp:DataGrid ID="datagrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" width="725px" BackColor="Gray" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="#DEBA84" Font-Size="XX-Small" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1">
    <HeaderStyle font-size="XX-Small" font-names="Verdana" font-bold="True" horizontalalign="Center" forecolor="White" bordercolor="White" backcolor="#1E3769" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor = "Gray" CssClass = "row" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass = "row" />
    <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="Login_Last_Name">
    <ItemTemplate> <a style="color: #000000;" href="mailto:<%# Container.DataItem("Login_Email")%>"> 
    <%# Container.DataItem("FullName")%> </a> </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
  <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="160px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataField="Agency_Name" HeaderText="Agency Name" SortExpression="Agency_Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
  <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="110px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone Number" SortExpression="Login_Phone"></asp:BoundColumn>
  <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataField="LoginType" HeaderText="User Type" SortExpression="Login_Type"></asp:BoundColumn>
  <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="115px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataField="AcctActive" HeaderText="Account Active" SortExpression="Login_Account_Active"></asp:BoundColumn>
  <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Details">
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <a style="color: #000000;" href="javascript:openDetail('userDetail.aspx?id=<%# Container.DataItem("Login_ID")%>');">
    Details </a> </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
  <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="25px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate> <a style="color: #000000;" href="edAccounts.aspx?f=e&id=<%# Container.DataItem("Login_ID")%>"> 
    Edit </a> </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want the Full Name column (first column, FullName) to be in alphabetical order by default, and then if they click on a specific column then that column should arrange itself alphabetically. This used to work until I applied the above solution to paginate based on the letter in the name.

I have tried modifying the SQL queries and including "ORDER BY FullName" and "ORDER BY LOGIN.Login_Last_Name" and many other things but can't seem to get it to order by this by default, nor does any other column sort when clicked on as should occur. Somehow the alphabetic pagination is not allowing these fields to be sorted any further.

This is ASP.NET 2.0 with VB. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx) and i as a personal note I would recommend using the example with the ObjectDataSource as it allows you to separate your presentation layer (pages) prom your data access layer (classes that execute sql and retrieve the data)

Comment: That example doesn't work for me because I have different queries depending on permissions, and doing the data source this way doesn't let me use this conditional logic.

Comment: Notice that depending on a session variable, a different query is executed.

Comment: And this article is confusing, it is unclear which code I need, all of it doesn't work. Any other examples that are a little more clear?

Comment: Sure you can, you can customize the methods you call with your objectdatasource to include that extra parameter (Session("Agency_Name")) and create your query accordingly. This example (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Optimized_Paging_And_Sort.aspx) should be more detailed, it's in C# not visual basic, but you should be able to read it and adapt it easily.